# What does '48 hours before departure' mean?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I was advised that I have to confirm my flight "48 hours before the departure".
What does that mean exactly?
"48 hours before the departure" is just a "point" of time, not a period.
I don't think it means I have to do confirm the flight 'exactly' 48 hours before the departure because doing so almost impossible.

The possibilities are

1. Before '48 hours before the departure'
2. After '48 hours before the departure'
3. Around '48 hours before the departure'

I'm really confused.

Comment: What airline is the flight with?  Very few airlines require you to re-confirm bookings now days, although many travel agencies/etc still (incorrectly) advise people to do so.

Comment: @Doc Thats what I thought

Comment: Reconfirmation was discussed here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7808/what-is-ticket-reconfirmation-and-why-does-it-exist

Comment: It was a general question, not about specific flight. When I used international flights reserved online, I've never done such 'confirmation' but there was no problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you should confirm your flight *by* 48 hours prior to departure.

In reality your window is likely to be from a few hours before that point to a few hours after. And it can be essential for some flights, as if you don't confirm then they may allocate your seats to someone else.

Comment: I've reconfirmed flights a week or more before departure, when it was unlikely I'd be able to do so later. Usually no problem, though the girl at the other end may have extra work to do looking for the future flight in the system

Comment: You're right - the ones which do have a problem just tend to tell you to call back later.